# How to create clean url using .htaccess for multiple parameters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration

I try to make clean URLS to my web site. 
The desired format is: site/category/num example site/sport/3

Both category and page are optional parameters. So i have three rules. The problem is rule three. It only work in first time.

User enter site - tule 1. OK.
User navigate and pick category. Rule 2... OK.
User navigate and want page 2 page. (rule 3) OK. 
User want see more items in page 3 (rule 3) Error..

I got parameter site/category/category/3 and navigatioin fail. Now i dont get why do i get category two times.

My .htaccess file work almost.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I still get same double category.

Comment: It's not a problem with htaccess. You need to add `<base href="/">` in your html code header.

Comment: Yap my links are broken...  ok fixed.
Now server respon 404 errors to 200 code.... eny hints for that?